# Problem with multiple path to new domain redirects when paired with fallback for everything else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect specific paths on an old site to specific paths on a new domain. For anything not on the specified paths, I want it to redirect to the new domain's base path. I can get the specific paths to work, but as soon as I setup the redirect for everything else it just pushes all paths to the the base path on the new domain.

**Example of what is wanted:**

```
  http://www.olddomain.com/australia
  http://www.olddomain.com/australia/hello
  # Both go to http://www.newdomain.com/australia

  http://www.olddomain.com/brazil
  http://www.olddomain.com/brazil/hello
  # Both go to http://www.newdomain.com/brazil

  http://www.olddomain.com/china
  http://www.olddomain.com/australia/hello
  # Both go to http://www.newdomain.com/china

  http://www.olddomain.com/some-landing-page
  # Goes to http://www.newdomain.com
```

**Here is what I am using:**

```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/brazil/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/pt-br/brazil
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/australia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-au/australia
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/china/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-cn/china
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/colombia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/es-co/colombia
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/india/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-in/india
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/indonesia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/indonesia
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/italy/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/it-it/italy
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/japan/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/malaysia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-my/malaysia
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/mexico/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/es-mx/mexico
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/poland/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-pl/poland
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/singapore/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-sg/singapore
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/south-africa/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-za/south-africa
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/se-asia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/asia
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/office/united-kingdom/london/contact-us(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-gb/united-kingdom
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/united-kingdom/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-gb/united-kingdom
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/united-states/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-us/united-states

  # Everything else
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com
```

When I keep that bit under "Everything else" enabled it pushes everything to newdomain.com. However, when I disable it, all the paths I specify work as designed, but the rest stay on the old domain.

**I also tried this:**

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com [R=301,NC]
```

**And this:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomaincom\.docksal$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to do all the things I want it to do? Specifically, how do I get it to execute a "RedirectMatch" as soon as it matches?

Comment: Do you have old and new domain pointing to the same server directory here, so that this .htaccess applies for both? That would explain it of course, your old brazil URL gets redirected to `/pt-br/brazil` first, and then that request gets redirected again, based on that last directive.

Answer (score 0):

Keep every rule on `mod_rewrite` and **must clear your browser cache** before testing this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^brazil/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/pt-br/brazil [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^australia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-au/australia [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^china/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-cn/china [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^colombia/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/es-co/colombia [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^india/(.+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/en-in/india [L,R=301,NC]
# and all other specific rules


# and catch-all rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomaincom\.docksal$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Same problem when I try it. The catch-all rule overrides all the others.

Comment: No it won't because it is checking conditions that matches `olddomaincom` in URL whereas all previous rules have already redirected to `newdomain`.

Comment: I just tried it. It did not work. I copied your lines and changed the domains to the appropriate ones.

Comment: I tested Brazil and Australia.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: I was trying via incognito mode. I checked the network tab and it redirects from "brazil" to "brazil/" to "https://www.newdomain.com".

Comment: incognito mode uses cache unless you click on disabling the cache.Once that is done test some URL that should go to catch-all rule and then test that should not.